# Is "Did you not tell me..." proper English?

Tags: grammar

Is "Did you not tell me..." proper English, as opposed to "Didn't you tell me?"

Comment: Yes, it's "proper English". Is there anything you don't understand about why using the contracted form effectively results in the negating ***not*** being moved to *before* the pronoun "you" in this example? Other than that, this looks like General Reference, even for ELL.

Comment: *Did you not...* is not the casual form. It can imply that the speaker is miffed.  When it is used, it is often used not with the tone of a question but with the tone of a rebuke.

Comment: @TRomano is correct. Quite a sharp rebuke too.

Answer (score 3):

Did you not tell me/Didn't you tell me?

Grammatically, both of the sentences are correct.

The first negative question, which is uncontracted type, is usually used in formal English.  On the other hand, the second negative question, which is contracted type, is very much common in both spoken and written English.

They are almost similar in meaning,

Answer (score 2):

In both questions you are placing the auxiliary verb did (which puts the sentence in the past tense) BEFORE the actual subject/noun,

- Did you not = Ok.
- Didn't you = The contraction between Did + Not    still doesn't
  change the Verb-before-Subject/Noun rule, so it should    be
  acceptable, although the previous sentence is definitely more
  formal.

Perhaps "Didn't you?" would be more appropriate in Tag Questions, e.g., "You did tell me to do that, didn't you?" or "You haven't done it, have you?".

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

*Did you not tell me to eat the apple? 
Didn't you tell me to eat the apple?
Did not you tell me to eat the apple?*

The first two sentences are proper and equivalent.  The third form is not a currently used colloquial interrogative form.  As a declarative sentence:
*I did not tell you to eat the apple.*
 The phrase *"did not"* can be used and is colloquial.

Comment: Noting that 'Did not you tell me to eat the apple?' Has been used historically, but has dropped out of common usage as the more informal 'Didn't' has become prevalent.

Comment: @JonStory  **Good point**  That is why I said *"not used"* rather than *"incorrect"*

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't say your answer is wrong, I just wanted to make it clear that "not used" in this case doesn't necessarily mean "has never been used" - some things are both :)

Comment: @JonStory What is the correct way of stating that a form should not be used because it's incompatible with colloquial usage as opposed to grammatically incorrect??

Comment: I'd just state it as 'While all three forms are technically correct, only the first two are used in regular conversation. You may see the latter occasionally, or in historical texts, but I'd generally avoid using it other than in historical writing'.

Comment: The last sentence would normally be expressed *Was it not you who told me to eat the apple?*

Comment: @Jon: Was *"did not you tell me?"* historically used in speech, or was it just an expanded written version of the spoken *"didn't you tell me?"* I haven't been able to find any evidence either way.

Comment: As far as I'm aware it was both, but I've mostly heard of it in an ultra-formal context - eg courts and similar. Whether that's because there are better records of court communication is another question

Comment: On and I wouldn't swear the exact phrase 'did not you tell me' was used - that sounds a little 'wrong' as a sentence.

Comment: @JonStory I have modified my answer as per your comments.

Comment: *"Did not you tell me to eat the apple?"* <== That would most likely be considered to be ungrammatical in today's standard English. In general, the word "not" does not come between a subject and the auxiliary verb (as it does in your example). There are exceptions, such as those involving a heavy subject or an inverted conditional, but they are relatively rare.

Comment: @Jon: I'm not convinced. Jane Austen used *"did not you"* multiple times, but her works do not seem to contain a single instance of *"didn't"*. One 19th century transcription from the [House of Commons](http://books.google.com/books?id=sFMTAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA329&dq=%22did+not+you%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AWZJVM3qJLiJsQT_1IHADQ&ved=0CDYQ6AEwBA#v=snippet&q=%22did%20not%20you%22&f=false) contains *"did not you"* 34 times, and *"didn't"* once. My theory is that *"did not you"* was never commonly used in speech, but that during the 19th century, *"didn't you"* was often transcribed *"did not you"*.

Comment: That's precisely my point? Historically, "Did not you?" was used with some regularity, and in the last 150 or so years, more informal contractions eg "Didn't you?" have taken over. That's not to say "Didn't you" was never used in the past, nor that "Did not you?" is never used now... just that the trend has been towards the informal, as with most language. My point was really only to make sure the reader understood that although current usage would almost always be "Didn't you?" even in formal use, that "Did not you" is not necessarily wrong, especially if being read in an older document/text.

Answer (score -1):

'Did you not tell me?' is rather formal, but I would not say that that makes it 'proper' English. 'Didn't you tell me?' is fine in everyday speech and less formal writing.

Comment: I can't possibly endorse an answer claiming the uncontracted form isn't "proper". If anything, it's actually *more* "proper".

Comment: Different uses of the word "proper" :-)  Proper ain't always proper.  I upvoted that downvote, because tunny just needs to make his meaning a little clearer. He means "appropriate".

Comment: I did not say the uncontracted form wasn't proper. I said that the lack of contraction did not make it 'proper English'. It doesn't Both the contracted and uncontracted forms are proper (=correct, up to standard).

Comment: Both are proper English, but the contracted version is the only version in common usage.